# how can i write this code without List?

Tags: c#, .net

How can i write this code without `List`? I have to write this code without any other classes(collections, generics...) only using `String` array. I also can't use `Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);` parameter to find all directories.

**Note: you can write other function which adds directions in `String` array.**

```
static void WriteDirectories(string rootDir) {
        // Write the first item
        Console.WriteLine(rootDir);

        // Create a list of sub directories
        List<string> subDirs = new List<string>();
        String[] arr = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDir);
        for(int i =0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
            subDirs.Add(arr[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < subDirs.Count; i++) {
            // Write the current sub directory item
            Console.WriteLine(subDirs[i]);

            // Add any sub folders under this item to our list
            subDirs.AddRange(Directory.GetDirectories(subDirs[i]));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why all these odd restrictions?

Comment: The only differenec betwee a T[]* and otherCollection<T> is that those other collections tend to automagically grow if you try to add above current capacity. Usually they do that by encapsulating a array. Allocate a new, bigger one. Transfer all the old data. Then add the new date. *Arrays do not actually use Generics. Variably typed arrays predate generics by a decades or so, but the useage is pretty similar. Basically you need a Add and remove Function that does the same work as a Add and Remove function provided as part of all the other Collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply write a function which combines two arrays instead of `AddRange` method and put all  directories in your `String` array.

```
static void WriteDirectories(string path) {
            Console.WriteLine(path);

            String[] dir = Directory.GetDirectories(path);

            for (int i = 0; i < dir.Length; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine(dir[i]);
                Add(ref dir , Directory.GetDirectories(dir[i]));
            }
        }

        static void Add(ref String[] dir , String[] subDir) {
            if (subDir.Length == 0) return;

            String[] temp = new String[dir.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++) {
                temp[i] = dir[i];
            }

            dir = new String[dir.Length + subDir.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++) {
                dir[i] = temp[i];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < subDir.Length; i++) {
                dir[i + temp.Length] = subDir[i];
            }
        }
```